# Indexing R matrix or data frame row-by-row

Tags: r

How can I select R data frame or matrix entries row-by-row, specifying the column for each row? For instance, if I have an n-by-3 matrix `mat` and a vector of length n with values in {1, 2, 3} (say `ind`), how can I get an n-length vector back, where the i-th entry is row i, column `ind[i]` of `mat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do `diag(mat[1:n, ind])` (didn't see an answer for this question so figured I'd put it out there).